# Analyzing CPU usage across multiple servers

Tags: cpu-usage, analysis

I am having some load issues with one of my servers, it's running Xen with various guests and with the current 7 it's at its limit.

However it tends to lag every now and then and we'd like to figure out what is causing this.

Is there some kind of application/tool that can analyze what process this is, and do this across multiple servers (Perhaps merge the data, or list it next to eachother).

Servers are running Debian 5.0 64-bit.

Comment: When I see a slow down on most VM environments, its usually due to inadequate hard disk I/O.  So pay attention to that as well.

Comment: I did so, the IO wait or whatever its called was hovering between 1 and 3 percent, which from what I understand is acceptable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Munin is a good thing (I used it for years). However I prefer [Collectd](http://collectd.org) nowadays. For small(er) setups Munin is ok. Collectd should be used for special needs (eg. large setups, fine grained statistics).

Comment: Hmm, it looks interesting and might even use less CPU than munin, however as it doesn't generate graphs only collects data, I would like to still have some kind of web frontend for it.

Comment: @Xeross: yeah it is true.

Comment: I will look into collectd once I have some free time to set it up, looks very promising. Just a bit more cumbersome to get the actual graphs.

Answer (score 3):

Give this a shot:

http://munin-monitoring.org/

Comment: I <heart> munin.

Comment: Yes it gives me CPU graphs but not the data I need (CPU usage of specific processes, including the usage of things that run through cron).

Answer (score 0):

Munin is great, However i prefer Cacti!
http://www.cacti.net/

To graph specific "processes" / "crons" is going to take some work on your behalf.

Basically.. You need to set it up in snmp, so that either cacti/munin can grab the stats through a certain OID..

Otherwise you will just get the standard "cpu" configuarition that is configured..

Hope this makes it clear :D

Comment: Cacti also provides some more advanced notification features if I recall correctly, however I prefer munin because I can easily write plugins for that.